# Changing date format while inserting database using Razor Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker, jquery-select2

I am using Oracle DB and my date-field format in DB is like MM-DD-YYYY. But i want to show the date as DD-MM-YYYY. I am using Jquery Select2 Add-On and i can change the date-field while selecting from datepicker as below:

```
     <div class="datetimepicker input-append " >
<input class="input-medium input-block-level" data-format="**dd/MM/yyyy**" 
data-val="true" data-val-date="The field ORDERDATE must be a date."
id="TARGETDATE" name="TARGETDATE" placeholder="Tarih Seçiniz" type="text">
```

The problem is that, i am unable to insert the date data into the DB when i select the date value like 23/2/2012. I think i need to change the format while inserting the DB.

I tried to use change date-format in my model but i could not do.

How can i change the date value before inserting to the DB ?

Comment: Is the date field in your database a date or string datatype?

Comment: My datafield is date.